# "Good Programming" Replacement for exit statement

Tags: loops, fortran

I have a fairly simple structure:

```
do i = 1,x
  if (condition) then
    do_stuff
    exit
  end if
end do
```

If the `do`-loop gets big enough, the `exit` statement wouldn't be good anymore (I look at it approx. like I look at `go to` statements).

I'm looking for a cleaner way to exit the loop when appropriate so that it is also more clear what is happening for somebody else looking over my code.

One thing I thought of that might clean up would be something along the lines of

```
lkeepgoing = .true.
iterator   = 1
while (lkeepgoing) then
  if (condition) then
    do_stuff
    lkeepgoing = .false.
  end if
  iterator = iterator+1
end while
```

While I think it clears up why I want to exit the loop without having to look through the whole loop, it looks overly complicated I think.

So the question: How do you exit `do`-loops when a condition is met in a clear, clean way that doesn't use spaghetti-code-prone statements?

Comment: If it helps, view `exit` as very different from a `goto`, if you must see it as a `goto` then a `goto` where the target has to be in a very specific and well-defined place.

Comment: Note, that your two code snippets are not doing the same, in the first you probably want to have the do_stuff before the if condition. Then you could also have a single line for the exit: `if (condition) EXIT`. The standard even says, that it will do exactly this for a while loop: If loop-control is [ , ] WHILE (scalar-logical-expr), the effect is as if loop-control were omitted and the following statement inserted as the first statement of the do-block: `IF (.NOT. (scalar-logical-expr )) EXIT`.

Comment: In addition to the great advice by HighPerformanceMark, sometimes you can employ the `do while` loop.

Comment: My reasoning for the closure: 1. Eventhough the other question uses different name for `exit` (`break`), it is the same and that question is not language specific (no language tag). 2. That question got closed even back then, when the rules were more relaxed. Today's equivalent of that closure reason is "primarily opinion based".

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the way your first code snippet uses `exit`.  A little jump such as that is hardly *spaghetti code*.  And compared with your second snippet it's considerably clearer that you are making a disciplined early exit from a loop when a certain condition is met.

Bear in mind that `exit` is very confined in where it can jump to, while `go to` can be used to jump all over the place.

Don't adhere to one-size-fits-none rules such as *never use goto* too strictly, certainly not when they make code worse.

Comment: Also, there is the possibility to have named loops. In this case, the flow is even more clear. The loop starts as `my_super_loop: do ...`, ends as `end do my_super_loop`. Within that loop you can use `exit my_super_loop`. It is especially useful for nested loops.

Comment: That was my thinking also. But my superior told me it's bad practice and I can't use it...

Comment: I kind of could see his argumentation, but I can't find a way thats better..

Comment: if you must abide by your superior's rules then shouldn't you be asking him this question?